# send mail without waiting of response java

Tags: java, email, smtp

I have one form from which multiple user can register. Now I am sending mail from domain binding mail server and that mail server is too slow which is taking almost 40 - 60 sec to send mail. I want like other code run as its real behaviour but sending mail code be like, I don't want wait till execution of send mail. And I am using mail API in java.

Comment: Please post some code examples of how you are doing it now

Comment: Use an ExecutorService to decouple sending-tasks from your main line of execution.